# mysqldump removes comments in triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I dumped my DB from a server and moved it to another. Everything was perfect, except all comments in all my triggers were gone. 
I found [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23002) that I should run `mysql --comments -uroot -p`. I do it, MySQL logs me in but when I run `mysql --help --print-defaults`, the `comments` variable is `FALSE` again.

Probably I can live without these comments, but still I'd be grateful if someone could give me a hint on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the -R Option:

-R, --routines      Dump stored routines (functions and procedures).

Answer (score 1):

Well that's the option here. using `--comments` while restoring the dump. [Per Document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_comments)

```
-c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
                    default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
                    with --comments.
```

So try like

```
mysql -u user -p --comments < your_dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: BTW, what is the difference between -R and -c options?